# Changing the Horizontal pixels of website

Tags: theme, home

This is my website http://www.dirtrades.com and I’m currently using this theme (http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/). Although this theme is great and better, comes for free I still have the complaint for with its Horizontal size. It’s too large to fit in screen. I don’t think that Customers actually like scrolling the page searching for things they want. I want the website to fit in the page. Being an amateur in PHP, I really don’t have any idea how can do it. I know if the length is changed then I’ll have to change the size of images too, but isn’t this possible that the images get resized automatically? Anyways, if that’s too hard to incorporate then anyone can please help me in at least making my website page fit in the screen horizontally? I’m good with vertical size, that is scrollable and the customers wouldn’t mind in scrolling through width. So, in short I want help in following:

> 1)    Making the website fit in customer’s screen as per their browsers setting & resolution, automatically.

IF automatic accommodation of page is not possible, then

> 2)     Help with the code to at least make the website fit in full, horizontally so that customers do not have to scroll for horizontal view.
>   If you’re gonna suggest me a code change then it’s my folded hand request to please provide the code as well and the directory path where I should make the change. I’m a child in the world of coding and Magento so I don’t know anything. All I know is, I have to complete my website anyhow!

Please help me out and I’ll buy you a beer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set the width of your page to 100% :D

Comment: How can I do that? I mean where do I need to make the changes?

Comment: In the site I am currently working on there is a <div> that contains all other elements.  I can change the width attribute of that div to match the size I want it to consume within the page.  If I set that <div style="width:120%;"></div> it's width will take up 120% of the space, if I set it to 100% it will take up only the amount of space that is within the window, 80%, 200%, etc.